# Erro Segmentation fault (core dumped) Lista dupla circular

Tags: c, algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou tentanto fazer uma Lista circular dupla há horas. Já tentei corrigir todos os erros mas deu um erro 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' que não faço ideia do que seja. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Abaixo segue meu código:

```
//Arquivo circDuplList.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cdlist.h"


struct cdlst{
int info;
cdLst* ant;
cdLst* prox;
};

/*Create an empty circ dupl list*/
cdLst* create_empty(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

/*Insert a node to the front of the circular list*/
cdLst* insert_front(cdLst* cdl, int info)
{
cdLst* p = (cdLst*)malloc(sizeof(cdLst));
p->info = info;
p->prox = cdl;
if(cdl != NULL){
    cdLst* aux = cdl;
    while(aux->prox != cdl){
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
    cdl->ant = p;
    p->ant = aux;
    aux->prox = p;
}else{
    p->prox = p->ant;
    p->ant = p->prox;
}
cdl = p;
return cdl;
}

/*Insert a node to the end of the circular list*/
cdLst* insert_end(cdLst* cdl, int info)
{
    cdLst* n = (cdLst*) malloc(sizeof(cdLst));
    n->info = info;
    if(cdl != NULL){
        cdLst* p = cdl;
        while(p->prox != NULL){
            p = p->prox;
        }
        p->prox = n;
        n->prox = cdl;
        n->ant = p;
        cdl->ant = n;
    }
    else{
        n->ant = n->prox = NULL;
        return n;
    }
    return cdl;
}

/*Remove a node from the list*/
void retira(cdLst* cdl,int info)
{
    if(cdl == NULL){
        printf("The list is empty");
        exit(1);
    }
    cdLst* p = cdl;
    while(p->prox != cdl && p->info != info)
        p = p->prox;
    if(p->prox == cdl && p->info != info){
        exit(1);
    }
    if(p == cdl){
        cdl = cdl->prox;
        cdl->ant = p->ant;
    }
    p->ant->prox = p->prox;
    free(p);
}

/*Print the list*/
void cdl_print(cdLst* cdl)
{
    cdLst* p = NULL;
    printf("\n%d",p->info);
    p = p->prox;
    while(p != cdl)
        printf("\n%d",p->info);
}

/*Print the list in the reverse order*/
//void cdl_print_rev(cdLst* cdl);

/*Verify if the list is empty*/
int empty(cdLst* cdl)
{
    return cdl == NULL;
}

/*Free memory of the list*/
//void cdl_free();
```

```
//Arquivo main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cdlist.h"

int main(void){
    cdLst* l = create_empty();
    int v = empty(l);
    printf("%d",v);
    l = insert_front(l,3);
    v = empty(l);
    printf("%d",v);
    l = insert_front(l,2);
    l = insert_front(l,3);
    l = insert_front(l,8);
    l = insert_front(l,65);
    l = insert_front(l,3);
    cdl_print(l);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a lista é circular, então você não precisa percorrer até o fim dela no `insert_front` porque isso significa que o "fim" dela está logo antes do início. Portanto, no `insert_front`, no caso de `cdl` não ser `NULL`, você pode fazer apenas isso:

```
    p->prox = cdl;
    p->ant = cdl->ant;
    p->ant->prox = p;
    p->prox->ant = p;
```

Ou seja, liga o elemento novo o `cdl` e ao elemento que antecede o `cdl` e liga esses dois elementos ao `p`.

Da mesma forma, se a lista é circular então não faz sentido ter tanto o `insert_front` para inserir no início quanto o `insert_end` para inserir no final. O início e o final da lista são exatamente os mesmos lugares. Assim sendo, você só precisa de um deles.

Ao tentar inserir o primeiro nó, `cdl` é `NULL`. O `insert_front` faz isso:

```
cdLst* insert_front(cdLst* cdl, int info)
{
cdLst* p = (cdLst*)malloc(sizeof(cdLst));
p->info = info;
p->prox = cdl;
if(cdl != NULL){
    // ...
}else{
    p->prox = p->ant;
    p->ant = p->prox;
}
```

Observe a ordem de como os ponteiros de `p` serão definidos:

```
p->prox = cdl;
p->prox = p->ant;
p->ant = p->prox;
```

A segunda linha (`p->prox = p->ant;`) vai copiar lixo do `p->ant` para o `p->prox`, sobreescrevendo o `cdl`. Nesse momento, o `p->ant` é lixo porque não foi definido em lugar nenhum. A terceira linha não produzirá qualquer efeito.

O que você precisa no caso do `cdl` ser `NULL` é disso:

```
p->prox = p;
p->ant = p;
```

O motivo é que a lista é circular, logo quando ela começa com um só elemento, esse próprio elemento tem a si mesmo como próximo e anterior.

Ainda no `insert_front`, você tem isso:

```
return cdl;
```

Na primeira vez, `cdl` é `NULL`, ele vai criar o primeiro nó da lista e retornar `NULL`. Retornar `NULL` significa que você cria um nó e o perde logo em seguida. Dessa forma, você nunca consegue criar nada! O que você queria retornar é `p`.

Na função `cdl_print`, isso não tem como dar certo por motivos óbvios:

```
cdLst* p = NULL;
printf("\n%d",p->info);
```

Ainda na `cdl_print`, veja esse código:

```
p = p->prox;
while(p != cdl)
    printf("\n%d",p->info);
```

Observe que como `p` nunca é alterado dentro do `while`, então isso é um loop infinito.

Não verifiquei a função `retira` e desconsiderei a `insert_end`. Também removi a `create_empty` e a `empty` porque as considero desnecessárias, vez que `create_empty` apenas retorna `NULL` sempre sem fazer mais nada e `empty` apenas verifica se algo é `NULL` ou não e você não precisa de uma função para fazer isso.

Seu código ficou assim:

```
//Arquivo circDuplList.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cdLst{
    int info;
    struct cdLst* ant;
    struct cdLst* prox;
} cdLst;

/*Insert a node to the front of the circular list*/
cdLst* insert_front(cdLst* cdl, int info) {
    cdLst* p = (cdLst*)malloc(sizeof(cdLst));
    p->info = info;
    if (cdl != NULL) {
        p->prox = cdl;
        p->ant = cdl->ant;
        p->ant->prox = p;
        p->prox->ant = p;
    } else {
        p->prox = p;
        p->ant = p;
    }
    cdl = p;
    return p;
}

/*Print the list*/
void cdl_print(cdLst* cdl) {
    printf("\n%d",cdl->info);
    for (cdLst *p = cdl->prox; p != cdl; p = p->prox) {
        printf("\n%d",p->info);
    }
}

int main(void){
    cdLst* l = NULL;
    l = insert_front(l,3);
    l = insert_front(l,2);
    l = insert_front(l,3);
    l = insert_front(l,8);
    l = insert_front(l,65);
    l = insert_front(l,3);
    cdl_print(l);
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
3
65
8
3
2
3
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/Rh6Mag)